# Exclude folders and files from build

Tags: intel-xdk

I have a mercurial repository and some visual studio files (I am using TypeScript) that I don't want included in my XDK build, but still need to be in the project directory. Is there a way to get Intel XDK to ignore them? I tried using the ignore setting but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the "Projects Tab" there are two directories that define your project: "Project Path" and "Source Directory." Project Path should always point to the "root" directory that contains your "project.xdk" file (it represents the top-level of your project). Source Directory can point to a subdirectory within the project that contains only those files that are germane to the build (it should contain the "source" files that actually represent your project).

If some of these other files need to be within this "Source Directory" then the "Exluded File Types" is the option that causes those files to be ignored. YOu can use the * wild card to exclude files. Note that the default exclude string (.git,.GIT,.svn,.SVN,.cvs,.hg,.HG, .CVS,.ignore,.IGNORE,.DS_Store) contains a list of directories. So, for example, you might include .hg in that list. If you've got some file extensions you want to exclude you would add those by using something like *.py, for example.

Comment: Thank you, so is not there any easy way how to exclude some directories like in git with .gitignore. I using bower for manage JavaScript libraries and for example Phaser have except build have also heaps of other stuff as documentation, resources and etc...

Comment: See the first paragraph above, that should do what you need. There is no way to put this list in a separate file, like a .gitignore, if that is what you are asking. But you can exclude entire directories, as described above.